# How to keep a private copy of a public repository up to date?

Tags: git, github

**Context:**
I have a private copy of twilio react project and have developed a lot of things over that considering it to be my master branch (directly pushing commits to it). While developing it, I have noticed twilio developers pushed a lot of fixes for several components. What would be the best way to merge those changes into my current private copy of their repository?

**Problem:**
How to maintain a copy of a public project privately and still developing over it?

Comment: "What would be the best way to merge those changes into my current private copy of their repository?" - `git fetch` - `git pull` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the copy was done by cloning the  public repository, and pushing it to a private repository, that would enable you to, as commented, fetch from the public repository, and merge the public branch to your private one.

That approach would not be possible if you have created a new private repository from scratch and just copied the sources from the public repository.

Comment: Seems to be the only solution I guess. But that would produce a lot of merge conflicts or atleast conflicts on those files which were updated on both public and private repository

Comment: One more solution that I can think of is to make changes in such a way that they are plug n play in nature. Kind of an external package or npm repo which will inject changes on the core files as soon it was initiated on mount. But that would also rely on the changes done by devs in public repository

Comment: @AshishBairwa I agree regarding the risk of merge conflicts. That kind of approach works better when you add to the code instead of modifying concurrently common part of the code.